# Is it possible to use Lightning Sync and still be on Salesforce Classic?

Tags: salesforcedx

I want to sync Salesforce to Outlook. Since Salesforce no longer supports Salesforce for Outlook and my org is still using the Classic UI, can I use Lightning Sync?

Answer (score 2):

Lightning Sync is just a name just like Lightning Platform, Lightning Connect and soo on.... It has nothing to do if you use Classic or Lightning.

[Check docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_sync_admin_overview.htm&type=5), it says it's for both Classic and Lightning

[image]